# Regex for input field which accepts percentage with 2 decimals

Tags: regex

Please help me with a regex to validate on a text field to accept.
It should accept:

- 0
- .50
- 100
- 0.01
- 50. 
- 10.0
- 99.99

It shouldn't accept:

- 100.01
- 50.567

I have an almost working regex with me which accepts unlimited number of decimals, in case it helps:

```
^(0*100{1,1}\.?((?<=\.)0*)?%?$)|(^0*\d{0,2}\.?((?<=\.)\d*)??)$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex could be the one you're looking for:

```
^(?:\d{1,2}\.\d{0,2}|100|\d{1,2}|\.\d{1,2})$
```

https://regex101.com/r/sLt1g1/1

Comment: i see you went through some iterations to come up with the correct answer. Thanks a ton @Cristiano!

Comment: Yes, I would have liked to have found a more elegant solution!

Comment: do you see any way to make it accept ".5"?

Comment: ".5" is accepted

Comment: you're right, ".5" is accepted. but since its an input field, the user will be blocked from inputing just "." before they type "5". can it accept just "." as well?

Comment: Ok, I understand. Try ^(?:\d{1,2}\.\d{0,2}|100|\d{1,2}|\.\d{1,2}|\.)$

Comment: It's the perfect regex now! Thanks a lot for helping me, was having trouble finding it online

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to allow empty strings:

```
^(?:(?:\d{0,2}\.)?\d{1,2}|100|\d{1,2}\.)$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:\d{0,2}\.)?` Optionally match 0-2 digit and `.`
  - `\d{1,2}` Match 1-2 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `100` Match 100
  - `|` Or
  - `\d{1,2}\.` Match 1-2 digits and `.`
- `)` Close non capture group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wn6EPb/1)

Comment: Simply brilliant and nice, thanks for sharing. But without knowing language how you guys are sure \d will work :) just asking here.

Comment: close, the decimals are limited to 2 places but it accepts 101 and above too.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 whats up with \d?

Comment: @desidigitalnomad, few regex engine don't support \d like they support [0-9] so I was asking him about the same, though it works for this scenario for sure.

Comment: @desidigitalnomad I see, I have updated it.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have used `\d` as it is in the pattern of the OP and mentioned that the pattern almost worked. Based on that, I assume `\d` works out. There is also a `(?<=\.)` from which I get that there are more than basic features supported. The thing is that in for example C# the `\d` can. match digits in any language.